# Is the 1.8 snapshot safe to build a world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to make a mini game world for minecraft. I would like to use the 1.8 snapshot to get the new blocks and mobs. But can it ruin my world because its a snapshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says clearly that snapshots can corrupt your world, so it is advised you keep regular backups of your minigame world.

Comment: So i can just back up the save a lot

Comment: @kingbluesapphire Yes.